# Help for: minolta riva zoom 125ex

Tags: repair, minolta, film-cameras

I am trying to find a service manual on the internet for the camera Minolta riva zoom 125ex,or any video regarding it,i believe some internal mechanisms have been misplaced and are out of places.
If anyone has anything please let me know!